# MapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps is working with connect for App component, for others its not going inside both the functions

Tags: react-redux, react-router-v4

This is the Main App component, its having other components as its routes, when I'm trying to get the state as props using connect for these components, then it is not even going inside the mapState and mapDispatch functions.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
   console.log("===============",state,"RRRRRRRRRRRRRRR",ownProps)
   return {todo: state.todos[0]}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
 return {
      addTodo: () => dispatch({type: 'ADD_TODO', text: "Done"}),
      counter: bindActionCreators(counter, dispatch),
      todo: bindActionCreators(todo, dispatch),
      login: bindActionCreators(login, dispatch)
  }
}

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

other component uses the same way(this is a route inside App component)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    console.log("+++++++++++++++++",state,"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",ownProps)
    return state;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    login1: bindActionCreators(login, dispatch)
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(Login)
```

Comment: Please post the content of `App` and `Login` components.

Comment: I figured it out, it was happening because of a small mistake. I was trying to import thing directly without braces which was defined as default for the file containing it.

Thank you @Krasimir for considering my query..